# Input file element inside SVG Rounded Rectangle

Tags: html, svg

Is it possible to keep input file element inside SVG?

I tried something like this, but it's not showing file element :

```
<svg width="50" height="10">
<rect x="5" y="2" rx="2" ry="2" width="50" height="10"style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5">
<input type="file"name="upload">
</svg>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the svg [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) element :

```html
<svg width="80" height="40">
<rect x="5" y="2" rx="2" ry="2" width="70" height="30"style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5"/>
<foreignObject width="70" height="30" x="7" y="3"><input type="file"name="upload"></foreignObject>
</svg>
```